# Get-ChildItem product used differently by Get-Content

Tags: powershell

There seems to be a difference between these two uses of `Get-ChildItem`.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\SVN\SSIS\AtomicLoad\Atomic_NPI\*.dtsx'
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\SVN\SSIS\AtomicLoad\Atomic_NPI' -Filter '*.dtsx'
```

They both report using Get-Member that they produce `TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo`.

However, using the `-Filter` parameter causes `Get-Content` to look for the file Name in the current working directory.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\SVN\SSIS\AtomicLoad\Atomic_NPI' -Filter '*.dtsx' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Path $_ }
```

Whereas, not using `-Filter` has `Get-Content` looking for the $_.FullName which works.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\SVN\SSIS\AtomicLoad\Atomic_NPI\*.dtsx' |
    ForEach-Object { Get-Content -Path $_ }
```

Why is this?

Comment: It's a good question that the linked post hopefully answers - in short: In Windows PowerShell, the stringification behavior of `System.IO.FileInfo` instances regrettably depends on the specifics of the `Get-ChildItem` command through which they were obtained - PowerShell _Core_ no longer has that problem.

Comment: Thanks, @mklement0. I tried on 6.1.1 and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: I would consider your approach bad practice anyway. Either use `$_.FullName` in situations like that, or remove the `ForEach-Object` and have `Get-Content` read the input from the pipeline.